# Does a multisite wordpress program run plugin instance per site?

Tags: wordpress

First, I would like to apologize if my question isn't clear enough - I'm new to wordpress so I might have some issues with the nouns.

Second, here's a description of my problem:
I have a plugin which creates tables in the DB.
What I want to accomplish is to create a multisite solution in which the same plugin is installed on all sites but each site see a different instance of DB.

This will allow me to have a some sort of multi tenant solution without re-writing the plugin.

Is this possible?

I'll appreciate your help.

Nadav

**Edit:**

That's the code I have in the Base Entity of the plugin:

```
 public static function getTableName()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb->base_prefix . static::$table;
    }
```

Should I change it to the following in order to support table per site?

```
 public static function getTableName()
{
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->prefix . static::$table;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `$wpdb->prefix` when creating your tables, then you will already have separate tables for each site.

```
global $wpdb;
$my_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$query = "CREATE TABLE $my_table...";
```

The above code would result in a separate table for each site, with names like `wp_2_my_table`, `wp_3_my_table`, etc (assuming you are using the default base prefix `wp_`).

The majority of plugins do not have to be updated to support multi-sites explicitly, so long as they adhere to best practices.

Conversely if you wanted to create a single table for all of the sites in the network, you would use `$wpdb->base_prefix`.

Just make sure you consistently use the correct prefix when creating or accessing tables.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables

Edit:

> Should I change it to the following in order to support table per site?

If you want separate tables for each site, then yes you will need to change it to use `$wpdb->prefix` rather than `$wpdb->base_prefix`. Note that if you're creating the tables in your activation hook, you'll have to re-install the plugin in order to create the new tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please have a look at the edit and see if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Hi, 
It seems like I was happy too early. After the change I got names like "wp_bb_customers"
where I was expecting to get something like wp3_bb_customers. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try var_dumping the prefix and base_prefix. Note that first blog's prefix is the base prefix. Starting from 2 and up you should have tables like `wp_2_posts`.

Comment: what's var_dumping? logging?
I suspect the issue is that the tables are created on "register_activation_hook". Maybe I should register to a different event?

Comment: Sorry, by var_dumping I meant calling `var_dump($wpdb->prefix)` to confirm that the prefix is what you expect. The activation hook is the correct place to setup your tables, are you activating your plugin per site?

Comment: The plugin is activated at the network level and then I use it in every site.
What do you think about the following post? Is it relevant?
http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/how-to-properly-create-tables-in-wordpress-multisite-plugins/

Comment: @nadavy Yes that article looks good to me. The issue is, if the plugin is activated at the network level, the activation hook isn't run per site. You can iterate over each site when you are network activating the plugin, or you can just activate per site.

Comment: So in order to activate per site (since I want to add sites dynamically) I'll have to implement the hooks that are mentioned in the article?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to handle the initial activation and iterate over every current site. You will also have to handle new sites being added by attaching your activation function to `wpmu_new_blog`.